# pass an array of data and display it in notifications

Tags: swift, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I do not know how to implement the function so that notifications come one by one from the data array. Here is my function that displays only one,last notification :

```
func addNotificationWithTimeIntervalTrigger(title :String){
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        content.body = "Body"
        //content.badge = 1
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)
        let reguest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timeInterval", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(reguest) { (error) in
        }
    }
```

Here I just pass the data from my tableView :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        UserNotificationManager.shared.addNotificationWithTimeIntervalTrigger(title:"aaa")
    default: break
    }
```

My notification : [image]

How to make the notifications go one by one from the array?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that every scheduled notification has a different identifier , otherwise the new one will replace the old

```
let reguest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timeInterval", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

Comment: it good but the notification is superimposed on each other, and not dropped one after another on the screen

Comment: this denpends on the time interval you set , you can make it in increasing order instead of static 3

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by using the `indexPath.row` to get an object from your data model. You have not shared your data model, but an array is a useful way to store your objects for situations like this.

With some changes, your custom function could look like this. You can now pass an integer index to get the correct object from your model.

```
func addNotificationWithTimeIntervalTrigger(title: String, index: Int) {

    guard let thisObject = yourDataModelArray[index] as? YourObjectType else { return }

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title // This could be taken from data model instead
    content.subtitle = thisObject.subtitle
    content.body = thisObject.body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)
    let reguest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timeInterval", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(reguest) { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            // Error handling
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could call it like this. No switch statement needed as it pulls data from your data model based on the `indexPath.row`. Note that you could also store the titles in your data model, meaning you would not have to pass this as an argument.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UserNotificationManager.shared.addNotificationWithTimeIntervalTrigger(title:"Custom title", index: indexPath.row)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Separate File created for local Notifications

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

struct NotificationHandlerStruct {
    static var notifyTimer : Timer?
}

class LocalNotificationHandler: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    static var shared = LocalNotificationHandler()

    //MARK: Schedule Notification
    func scheduleNotification(Title title: String, Subtitle subtitle: String, BodyMessage body: String, AlertContent contentRx:[AnyHashable:Any]) {
        /// Remove Previous Displayed Notification in case if you need
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ["gruveoCall"])
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        //adding title, subtitle, body and badge
        content.title = title
        content.subtitle = subtitle
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.body = body
        content.badge = 0
        content.userInfo = contentRx

        //getting the notification trigger
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.01, repeats: false)
        //getting the notification request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "gruveoCall", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        //adding the notification to notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)

         /// Comment Code below if you do not want to repeat same notification again after some interval of time
        if NotificationHandlerStruct.notifyTimer == nil {
            NotificationHandlerStruct.notifyTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
                self.sendNotification(NotificationContent: content)
            })
        }
        else{
            NotificationHandlerStruct.notifyTimer?.invalidate()
            NotificationHandlerStruct.notifyTimer = nil
        }

    }

    //MARK: Repeat Notification
    func sendNotification(NotificationContent content: UNMutableNotificationContent) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: ["gruveoCall"])
        //getting the notification trigger
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.01, repeats: false)
        //getting the notification request
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "gruveoCall", content: content, trigger: trigger)
        //adding the notification to notification center
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
    }

    //MARK: Stop Timer
    func stopTimer() {
        if NotificationHandlerStruct.notifyTimer != nil {
            NotificationHandlerStruct.notifyTimer?.invalidate()
            NotificationHandlerStruct.notifyTimer = nil
        }
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        //displaying the ios local notification when app is in foreground
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     LocalNotificationHandler.shared.scheduleNotification(Title: self.providerListArray![indexPath.row], Subtitle: "My Subtitle", BodyMessage: "Some Message", AlertContent: ["aps":["data":"your Content"]])
 }
```